# Find a comma saperated word from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, find

I am trying to find word from a string
I have a string like

```
         var str="Roof Garden, Garden, Hall, Children Room, Guest Room, Roof_Garden";
```

Now i want to find "Garden" in this string
 So i want to get only Garden not " Roof Garden" or Roof_Garden
Please suggest me any best way to find the exact word

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var str="Roof Garden, Garden, Hall, Children Room, Guest Room, Roof_Garden";
var res = str.split(", ");
var searchWord = "Garden"
var result = res.find(data => data == searchWord);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. I guess you are new, but you need to search for answers , it already
   available on many platforms.
2. I used to do same, telling from my experience. Its okay.

   ```
     var str="Roof Garden, Garden, Hall, Children Room, Guest Room,         Roof_Garden"; 

    var n = str.split(",");

     for (let i in n){
        if(n[i].trim()==="Garden"){
         alert(i)
        }
     }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code below:

```js
var str="Roof Garden, Garden, Hall, Children Room, Guest Room, Roof_Garden, Garden";

var searchString = 'Garden';

var filterResult = str.split(',').filter(s => s.trim() === searchString)

console.log(filterResult); // result as an array
```

I hope it's work

Answer (score -2):

You can use this method for a global search:
**str.match(/Garden/g);**